# How to set the output of JS code on Rubymine

Tags: visual-studio-code, rubymine

I would like to be able to see the output of codes on JS on Rubymine IDE, as if I were using quokka on VScode, once is use `console.log()`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RubyMine you need to execute (run or debug) JS code to see the output. Here is a feature request about Quokka functionality you can vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30896.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I hope they get this in JetBrains =)